# How to get an original function from the limit definition of a derivative?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, algorithms, reverse-math

Say I have
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}$$

If $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)|_{x=0} =
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{0+h}-e^0}{h},$$

how would I “back engineer” the derivative limit definition to satisfy the expression meaning expression-I equals expression-II. But we’re only given expression-II the limit expression so how do we find the “mystery” expression-I from expression-II.

I basically want to remove the guess work required to satisfy the two expressions, and if there’s even a general “algorithm” to follow?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you are asking. Do you want to integrate $e^x$?

Comment: I haven’t learned about integration yet so I’m sorry if the question doesn’t make any sense but I basically have this original function that’s being solved for its derivative so d/dx f(x) that I have no idea what it is and I want to find what it is(f(x)). I am only given the equivalent but in limit definition form. So I want to find that original function being used to find that limit we are given. I hope that helps sorry if it doesn’t lmk if there anything I can clarify, thank you!

Comment: Do you have d/dx f(x)=$e^x$?

Comment: Ahh I see thank you so much and I don’t have d/dx f(x) only the lim h->0. But this solves my problem appreciate all the help!

Comment: I think your comment got edited but to confirm I would need integration to “discover” the original expression?

Comment: I edited it myself. Are you asking how we can find $f(x)$ if we only know $d/dx f(x)$?

Comment: Oh no sorry how we find f(x) from only our lim h—> 0 expression

Comment: @CanadianBacon, $\lim_{h\to 0} (f(x+h)-f(x)/h$ is the definition of the derivative $f'(x)$ (as a limit). So I think you are asking how to recover $f$ from $f'$. Yes, $f'$ is defined as a limit.

Comment: @paulgarrett this is of course true but what Canadian Bacon wants to find out, if I have understood him correctly, is how he can see that the **first** formula is equal to $d/dx(e^x)$ evaluated at $0$. Why do you want to back-engineere in this case? It makes things only more complicated.

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing guys I’m going to add an image on the post to supplement it, giving the original problem from the paper.

Comment: @vitamind, I guess I'm not seeing that there is an issue in understanding that that expression is the derivative evaluated at $0$. Is it conceivably relevant that knowing the value of a derivative at $0$ gives very little information about what the function was?

Comment: And vitamin d this spot on, I would want to back engineer the problem to allow myself to relate it to the value of some expression equal to the lim h->0 expression. So ideally it would mean the derivative of “this” random function is equal to the limit as h approach 0 of some other expression. Allowing me to say “this limit” is also “this” allowing me to write it in two different forms with sorta a “proof”. Ex: ax=gyznnh. You could say ax is a lot simpler to write out than gyznnh. Lmk if that helps thanks!

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped I was really stuck on this one. Both answers given are excellent. Shoutout to @vitamin_d for reformatting the math for a more viewable experience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it boils down to (1) identifying that a given limit is the derivative of a function $f(x)$ at some point $x=a$, namely

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(h)}h$$

and (2) precisely picking out what the function $f(x)$ is supposed to be.

In the given example,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{\color{red}{0+h}}-e^{\color{red}0}}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h\implies f(x)=e^x\text{ and }a=0$$

and hence this limit is exactly the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$. If you know that $(e^x)'=e^x$, then the limit is simply $e$.

So the strategy is to recast the given limit into an expression involving the forward difference $f(a+h)-f(a)$.

Another example:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^{\frac13}-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\color{red}{1+h})^{\frac13}-\color{red}{1}^{\frac13}}h\implies f(x)=x^{\frac13}\text{ and }a=1$$

Then this limit would be $\frac13$, or the derivative $\left(x^{\frac13}\right)'=\frac1{3x^{\frac23}}$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

> The derivative of a function $f$ at a  point $a$ is defined as
> $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$

Setting $f(x)=e^x$ and $a=0$ this yields
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x\mid_0 = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{0+h}-e^{0}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}.$$

This would be the solution to your problem.

If I understood you correctly you want to have a step by step derivation, from the limit to the derivative. I don't think that's the aim of the book, it's about *observing* that these two expressions are equal and not about calculations.